# How to iterate through "pairs" of user and computer variables in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I've got a PowerShell deployment script that is meant to automate the spinning up of a domain environment.  I have 5 user accounts and 5 machines "pairs" like so:

Machines:
DT01
DT02
DT03
DT04
DT05

User accounts:
student1
student2
student3
student4
student5

student1 is the primary user of DT01, student2 is the primary user of DT02, and so on.

I have a snippet of code that runs each machine through a series of commands like so:

```
invoke-command -computername DT01{
do this
do that
do another thing
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" "DOMAIN\$using:student1"
do another thing
icacls "c:\somefolder" /grant DOMAIN\"$using:student1:w
```

Then I'd like this process to go through the next pair, so...

```
invoke-command -computername DT02{
do this
do that
do another thing
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" "DOMAIN\$using:student2"
do another thing
icacls "c:\somefolder" /grant DOMAIN\"$using:student2":w
```

....and eventually go through ALL the pairs.

I'm not sure how to write the array portion to get these students and PCs paired with each other and then iterate through the deployment commands.

Help please?

I tried Googling a lot, and chatgpt :-)

Comment: You should store PCs and students with their relations to each other as pairs together in a CSV file for example.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: something like `For($i=0;$i -lt $computers.count; $i++){Invoke-command -computername $computers[$i] {param($student);do this; do that; net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" "DOMAIN\$student)"} -argumentlist $Students[$i]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By getting input as csv file something like this
this code is not tested, please test before you execute in mass.

```
server,student
DT01,student1
DT02,student2
DT03,student3
```

and using Argument list

```
$csvdata = import-csv C:\Test\test.csv
foreach ($line in $csvdata) {
    invoke-command $line.server { param($student) net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" "DOMAIN\$using:student2"
do another thing
icacls "c:\somefolder" /grant DOMAIN\$student } -argumentlist $line.student
}
```

or by

```
$csvdata = Import-Csv "C:\Test\Test.csv" -Header server, student
ForEach ($line in $csvdata) {
$servername = $line.server
$user = $line.student

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ScriptBlock {
do this
do that
do another thing
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" "DOMAIN\$using:user"
do another thing
icacls "c:\somefolder" /grant DOMAIN\"$using:user":w
 }
}
```

Comment: Dilly B - that second example was exactly what I needed thanks!

Comment: @TenaciousB Glad it worked! Please mark it as an answer if you find it useful.